# mailchimp: which grouping values should be used in lists/subscribe api?

Tags: mailchimp, subscribe

I am using mailchimp 2.0 to add a subscriber and group membership.  The subscribe part works fine.  What I need to know is, from the form sample below, which values I should be providing in the parameters for the API.

Here's a snip from the subscribe embedded form sample produce by mailchimp:

```
<strong>App Registration </strong>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[6425][1]"
           id="mce-group[6425]-6425-0">
    <label for="mce-group[6425]-6425-0">Installed on Android</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[6425][4]"
           id="mce-group[6425]-6425-1">
    <label for="mce-group[6425]-6425-1">Installed on iOS</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<strong>Newsletter </strong>
<ul>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[6429][2]"
           id="mce-group[6429]-6429-0">
    <label for="mce-group[6429]-6429-0">Receive periodic newsletter</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I need to provide something like this for the groupings part of the parameters (using PHP):

```
$groupings => array (array ('id' => 6425, 
                            'groups' => array("Installed on Android")));
```

if I want the user to become a member of "Installed on Android".  The question is which of the values from the html should I be using?

```
value="1",
name="group[6425][1]", or
id="mce-group[6425]-6425-0"
```

The API documentation also says to provide an array of "names for this grouping".  Surely they don't want the actual UI text for the group as that could change on a whim.  I've tried using the actual text, which does work.  Nothing else I've tried works.  Is that what they really want?

Comment: You can use the actual UI name or the ID. Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/21635163/3257914 - The suggestion of calling lists/interest-groupings to get the ID format the API is looking for should help.

Comment: I did look at lists/interest-groupings but it only returns the text for the group, not any sort of id.  To be clear, I'm looking for a way to determine the "group", not the "grouping".  For the latter, I am using the id, 6425 in my example.